# Prove that a sequence is bounded using $\alpha$ convexity

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification, convex-analysis

I consider $J$ an $\alpha$ convex functional defined on $K$ a convex and closed subset of an Hilbert space and $(u_n)$ a sequence such that $J(u_n)$ is a decreasing convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

The $\alpha$ convexity of $J$ means that for all $u,v$ we have

$$
J(\frac{v+u}{2})\leq \frac{J(v)+J(u)}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{8}\lVert v - u\rVert^{2}
$$

We know that $J$ has a unique minimizer on $K$, we denote it $\bar{u}$.

Moreover, we have the following relation that holds for all $n$

$$
J(u_n) - J(u_{n+1}) \geq \alpha\lVert u_n - u_{n+1}\rVert^{2} 
$$

So the sequence $\lVert u_n - u_{n+1}\rVert$ converges to $0$.

I would like to prove that $(u_n)_n$ is bounded.

Attempt :

I have tried something which is not complete : for all $n$ we have

$$
\lVert u_n - u_{n+1}\rVert^{2} \geq (\lVert u_n\rVert - \lVert u_n\rVert)^{2}
$$

Combining this to the fact that $J(u_n)$ is a decreasing sequence and $J(\bar{u})$ is the minimum we get

$$
J(\bar{u})\leq J(\frac{u_n+u_{n+1}}{2})\leq \frac{J(u_n)+J(u_{n+1})}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{8}\lVert u - u_{n+1}\rVert^{2}\leq \frac{J(u_n)+J(u_{n+1})}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{8} (\lVert u_n\rVert - \lVert u_n\rVert)^{2} \leq J(u_n)- \frac{\alpha}{8} (\lVert u_n\rVert - \lVert u_n\rVert)^{2}
$$

Developpping the square we get

$$ 
\frac{\alpha}{8}\lVert u_n\rVert^{2}\leq J(u_n) - J(\bar{u}) +\frac{\alpha}{4}\lVert u_n\rVert\lVert u_{n+1}\rVert - \frac{\alpha}{8}\lVert u_{n+1}\rVert^{2}\leq J(u_n) - J(\bar{u}) +\frac{\alpha}{4}\lVert u_n\rVert\lVert u_{n+1}\rVert
$$

Then I am stuck here, I tried to write this like that in order to make us of the fact that the sequence $\lVert u_n - u_{n+1}\rVert$ converges to $0$ :

$$
\lVert u_n\rVert\left(\frac{1}{2} \lVert u_n\rVert - \lVert u_{n+1}\rVert\right)\leq\frac{4}{\alpha} (J(u_n) - J(\bar{u}))
$$

But the fact that for a given $\epsilon$ starting from a rank $N$ we have $\lvert\lVert u_n\rVert - \lVert u_{n+1}\rVert\rvert \leq\epsilon$ seems to not help so much here given the sense of the inequality.

From there I am not able to conclude, so so I am wondering if it is the good path ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the definition of $\alpha$-convexity for functions on Banach spaces?

Comment: Yes sure ! The one I have is that there exists $\alpha> 0$ such that $J(\frac{x+y}{2})\leq \frac{J(x)+J(y)}{2} -\frac{\alpha}{8}\lVert x - y\rVert^{2}$. If the function is continuous we get the usual convexity

Comment: Cool, so you don't actually have that $J(px+qy)\leq pJ(x)+qJ(y)-?\frac{\alpha}{2}{||x-y||}^2$, where $?$ is something (I am currently lazy to see what it would be). Interesting. I want to take a look at your question. Just tell me, is this your hypothesis, or is it an exercise? I.e. do you know for sure that it is true?

Comment: @cnikbesku It is a claim that is assumed in a proof I have read in a book but the claim is not really proven, I think the author is write I just don’t see how to proceed aha.